# StreamSets data not landing into table created on postgres db

Tags: sql, postgresql, pipeline, streamsets

I am using StreamSets to build a pipeline to land data from a table that sits in a sqlserver db to a table on postgres db.

```
JDBC Query Consumer  --> Timestamp --> JDBC Producer
```

The pipeline passes validation checks and runs successfully on preview mode. However, the problem is that the data does not land into the postgres table. 
I have checked the connection string and credentials and these should be right.

This is the error it throws in the logs.

> No parameters found for record with YY SELECT 'XX' AS fieldA, YY AS
>   fieldB, ZZ AS fieldC::rowCount:#; skipping

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

'No parameters found' means that there were no fields on the record that could be mapped to database columns. Check your field-to-column mappings. If they look correct, it might be a problem with case. Try enabling **Enclose Object Names** on the **JDBC** tab.

Comment: It was down to enclose object names and UpdatedDate field of data type timestamp datatype not matching between source (T-SQL) and destination (PostgresSQL)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that was the problem.